# Conditional addition of rows to a new column & deleting old column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

| State | County | Candidate | CandidateVotes | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Joe Biden | 13713 | ABSENTEE BY MAIL |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Joe Biden | 63 | FAILSAFE |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Joe Biden | 33 | FAILSAFE PROVISIONAL |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Donald Trump | 9122 | ABSENTEE BY MAIL |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Donald Trump | 26495 | ELECTION DAY |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Donald Trump | 42 | FAILSAFE PROVISIONAL |
| Pennsylvania | York | Donald Trump | 146733 | TOTAL |
| Pennsylvania | York | Joe Biden | 88114 | TOTAL |

The mode can be a variety of things, but the total number of votes will always be the total of the column for that candidate.  Also, some states/counties will keep a total rather than breaking everything down.  What I am looking to do is the same as what Pennsylvania is listed at the bottom.

This is my desired output:

| State | County | Candidate | CandidateVotes | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Joe Biden | 13809 | TOTAL |
| South Carolina | Beaufort | Donald Trump | 26537 | TOTAL |
| Pennsylvania | York | Donald Trump | 146733 | TOTAL |
| Pennsylvania | York | Joe Biden | 88114 | TOTAL |

I think the correct way to do this is to group by State, County and Candidate.  From here, add all of the modes for that respective candidate and create a new column with that total.  And where Mode = 'TOTAL', simply bring that over to the new column then delete Mode.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby and do a sum using the three columns State, County, and Candidate from the dataset.

```
df = df.groupby(['State', 'County', 'Candidate']).sum().reset_index()
```

This will give an output with the first four columns and then you can integrate the Mode column separately since it will have the static value.

```
df['Mode'] = 'Total'
```